# Http webserver array out of bounds error

Tags: java, http

i've been working on a simple HTTP web server in java. however i seem to be running into an issue where when i try to get the file name in the request i get an array out of bounds error even though its not out of bounds and i can clearly see it in the array. can anyone help code is below

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception{
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8080);

    while(true){
        Socket s= ss.accept();
        String ip = s.getInetAddress().toString();
        ConnectionHandler ch = new ConnectionHandler(s);
        ch.start();
        System.out.println(ip);

    }

public class ConnectionHandler extends Thread{

private Socket s;
private PrintWriter pw;
private BufferedReader br;

public ConnectionHandler(Socket s) throws Exception{
    this.s = s;
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
}

@Override
public void run(){
    String reqs = "";

    try {
        while(br.ready()){
            reqs += (char) br.read(); 
            //System.out.println(reqs);
            HttpRequest hr = new HttpRequest(reqs); 
            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse(hr);
            pw.write(res.response.toCharArray());


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        pw.close();
        try {
            br.close();
            s.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

}

```
public class HttpRequest {

 String fileName;

public HttpRequest(String reqs){

    String lines[] = reqs.split("\n");

    //System.out.println(lines[0]);
    String lines1[] = lines[0].split(" ");
    for(int i = 0;i<lines1.length;i++){
        System.out.println(i + lines1[i]);

    }
    fileName = lines1[1]; //error is here


}
```

}

```
public class HttpResponse {

private HttpRequest req;
String response;
private String root="H:/root";
private FileInputStream fis;
private File f;
public HttpResponse(HttpRequest hr) throws Exception {
    req = hr;
    if(req.fileName == null){
         f = new File("H:/root/helloworld.html");
         fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    }else{
         f = new File(root + req.fileName);
         fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    }


    response = "HTTP/1.1 200";
    response += "content-type: text/html \r\n";
    response += "Connection: close \r\n";
    response += "content-length: " + f.length() + "\r\n";
    response += "\r\n";
    int s;
    while((s=fis.read())!=-1){
        response += (char) s;
    }
    fis.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that:
`reqs += (char) br.read();`
only reads a single char from the input and after each read character you try to parse the request.

So you will end up in a situation where you only have "G" in reqs which would cause lines1 to be of length 1. `lines1[1]` would try to access the second element in that array, which doesn't exist.

Try moving the parsing of the request outside of the loop.

[EDIT] Better formatting support in the answers. This works as intended for me.

```
while (br.ready())  {
    reqs += (char) br.read();
}
HttpRequest hr = new HttpRequest(reqs);
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse(hr);
pw.write(res.response.toCharArray());
```

Comment: tried that but got same issue. i know its reading in the request correctly into the array cause i did a for each loop to check its the whole fileName = lines1[1]; that it doesnt like and im not sure why

Comment: Doing this works for me. (edit) I've updated the answer instead since the code was unreadable here.

Comment: That worked perfectly for me now i see where i was going wrong thank you for your help